# Angular : how to display a login page by default

Tags: angular

I am working on a springboot/angular(version 11.2.7) application. I want to display the login page on startup

Here is the index.html page

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Frontend</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the LoginComponent

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import {LoginService} from "./login.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html'
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  public formGroup: FormGroup;
  public error: boolean = false;

  private credentials = {username: '', password: ''};

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private loginService: LoginService, private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
        this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
          username: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.email, Validators.required])],
          password: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])]
        });
  }

  login() {
  this.credentials.username = this.formGroup.get('username').value;
  this.credentials.password = this.formGroup.get('password').value;
    this.loginService.authenticate(this.credentials, () => {
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/homepage');
    });
    return false;
  }

}
```

Here is the app.module.ts file

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component'
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpsInterceptor } from './http.interceptor';
import {ReactiveFormsModule} from "@angular/forms";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [{ provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: HttpsInterceptor, multi: true } ],
  bootstrap: [LoginComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Here is the AppRoutingModule

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import {LoginComponent} from "./login/login.component";
import {NgModule} from "@angular/core";


const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/login',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent
  }
  ];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes,
      { enableTracing: false })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Here is the Spring controller

```
package com.example.commission.controllers;

import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Map;

@RestController
// we allow localhost:4200 for testing purposes
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/message", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public Map<String, String> index() {
        return Collections.singletonMap("message", "Greetings from Spring Boot!");
    }

}
```

but when I browse http://localhost:8080/, I have the error message in the console

```
ERROR Error: The selector "ng-component" did not match any elements
    Angular 24
        selectRootElement
        locateHostElement
        create
        bootstrap
        _moduleDoBootstrap
        _moduleDoBootstrap
        bootstrapModuleFactory
        invoke
        onInvoke
        invoke
        run
        scheduleResolveOrReject
        invokeTask
        onInvokeTask
        invokeTask
        runTask
        drainMicroTaskQueue
        promise callback*scheduleMicroTask
        scheduleTask
        scheduleTask
        scheduleMicroTask
        scheduleResolveOrReject
        then
        bootstrapModule
    zUnb main.ts:11
    Webpack 6
        __webpack_require__
        0
        __webpack_require__
        checkDeferredModules
        webpackJsonpCallback
        <anonymous>
```

### UPDATE

I change the following

```
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers: [HttpClient]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html'
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
```

And app.component.html

```
<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6 offset-sm-3">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

### UPDATE 2

I changed the routing

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },

  // otherwise redirect to home
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes,
      { enableTracing: false })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

For incremental purpose AuthGuard return false and redirect towards login page

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';

//import { AuthenticationService } from '@app/_services';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(
    private router: Router
    //,private authenticationService: AuthenticationService
  ) { }

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
/*    const currentUser = this.authenticationService.currentUserValue;
    if (currentUser) {
      // logged in so return true
      return true;
    }*/

    // not logged in so redirect to login page with the return url
    this.router.navigate(['/login'], { queryParams: { returnUrl: state.url } });
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: 1). first check is user login.  2). if is not then redirect to login page else home page.

Comment: Hi Vinit_Saini, I did a quite similar thing (see UPDATE 2). If user is logged display HomePage, else redirect towards LoginPage. In my case to test the functionality, , the user is not logged (see AuthGuard) so at the moment it display LoginPage. But it does not resolve the issue I have